# Print an array outside the for loop java

Tags: java, android, arrays, wifi

I have a simple for loop for WIFI information, i want to use the `wifis[i]` outside the loop, pleeeease help me how can i do that since it is an array! I am able to get the first value in the array only.

```
// Setup WiFi
  wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

  // Register Broadcast Receiver
  if (receiver == null)
      receiver = new WiFiScanReceiver(this);

  registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
          WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
  Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");

  ArrayList<ScanResult> wifiScanList = new ArrayList<ScanResult>(wifi.getScanResults());

      wifis = new String[wifiScanList.size()];

    for( int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++){
      wifis[i] = ((wifiScanList.get(i).BSSID).toString()+" , "
            + String.valueOf(wifiScanList.get(i).level) +" , " + String.valueOf(wifiScanList.get(i).frequency));
    Log.e("WIFI list", " :  " + wifis[i]);
    }
```

Comment: sorry, what's the question?

Comment: @blackbelt how to print wifis[i] outside the for loop? i want the full array to be like this b4:75:00:13:bc:ce , -74 , 2672 then 00:75:00:13:ac:be , -64 , 2072

Comment: what does *print* print mean  for you?

Comment: @blackbelt just simply Log.e("WIFI list", " :  " + wifis[i]); to check my values

Comment: then `Log.e("WIFI list", " :  " +Arrays.toString(wifis));`

Comment: @blackbelt You saved my life, although i wanted the array without the brackets but it is fine, thank you sooooooo much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not due the usage of the array itself outside the for loop. It's the loop-local variable `i` that's not visible outside the loop.

If you want to access some element of the array `wifis` outside that loop then you can either directly provide the index value like - `wifis[0]` (the first element), or use some variable that's visible outside that loop.

Comment: I agree with Bhesh on this.

Comment: @Bhesh thanks for replaying, i know that i can print the wifis[0] only, but i want to print the other networks as well and because the number of networks is unknown i cannot assign 0,1,2,.. since in some conditions i may have one network and it will give an error!!!

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use an array somewhere, traditionally you write another for loop going over each element that's inside of the array, because an array is a collection of elements, one after the other:

```
for (int i = 0; i < wifis.length; ++i) {
   Log.e("WIFI list", " :  " + wifis[i]);
}
```

This way, first you will use wifis[0], then wifis[1], then wifis[2]
until you have wifis[wifis.length-1], provided there are so many elements.

Basically, you go over the array and use one after the other, from first to last.

You could also write a for-each-loop:

```
for (String str : wifis) {
    Log.e("WIFI list", " :  " + str);
}
```

This basically means "for each string str in wifis do the following..."